# How does $a^2_1-2a_1x+b^2_1-2b_1y=a^2_2-2a_2x+b^2_2-2b_2y$ become $2(a_2-a_1)x +2(b_2-b_1)y+(b^2_1-b^2_2)=0$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles

I came across this while reading "The Four Pillars of Geometry" (p.52) by Stillwell. He wants to prove that all points equidistant from two other points form a line. For this, he equates the distances between two points $(a_1, b_1)$ and $(a_2, b_2)$ and a general point $(x, y)$ on the line. After some steps, this comes up:

Which steps do I have to take, to transform the first equation to the second?
$$
a^2_1-2a_1x+b^2_1 -2b_1y = a^2_2-2a_2x+b^2_2-2b_2y
$$

$$
2(a_2-a_1)x +2(b_2-b_1)y+(b^2_1-b^2_2)=0
$$

Everything I achieved yet still contained $(a^2_1 - a^2_2)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thats a typo in the book.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if there are errata available? I could not find any via Google.